# Django pagination is repeating results

Tags: django, pagination, django-queryset

I have this weird pagination bug in Django: using `object_list` as a return of a view, but passing a "paginate_by" argument to it, it's repeating some of the results; Otherwise, if I remove the argument or set as `paginate_by=None`, the results are correct.

If using pagination, the quantity of results is maintained at a total, so, because there are repeated results, the last results are left out of the list, so they don't appear in the template.

Any ideas of what might be happening?

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/b4zinh27

Comment: Important info: the number of repeated results is equal to the number of links between the related many-to-many objects. Might be the best clue to get to the error.

Answer (score 33):

I had this problem also, but found a solution.

The problem was that i sorted the dataset by date. When i had multiple records with the same date, pagination showed wrong records.

What i did was i added another searchfield, id, so that the sortcriteria was unique for every record. And then it worked!

Before:

```
self.filtered_nesgames = self.filtered_nesgames.order_by('releasedate')
```

After:

```
self.filtered_nesgames = self.filtered_nesgames.order_by('releasedate', 'id')
```

HTH

Comment: 4 and a half years later, this is still what's going on. Thanks for this!

Comment: Is there a fix for this in coming Django releases? :(

Comment: Since it haven't been fixed in the recent 6 years and 4 months, it seems unlikely. Also: Yay for NES games :-)

Comment: 9 years later. Seems like this the only workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Aparently there's an [open issue about documenting how pagination works](https://github.com/alex/django-filter/issues#issue/13) with django-filter.

Try following the advice given by the issue submitter, bartTC.

Comment: what has this to do with the OP's question?